# Is there a queue equivalent for Guava CacheBuilder?

Tags: java, guava

I'm trying to queue a bunch of requests and process them later. Is there something like a Set (ideally a queue) with an expieAFfterWrite semantics like Google CacheBuilder?

Since I just have a bunch of values I feel using the CacheBuilder would be wasteful. Suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear why you need to expire values after a certain amount of time - can you explain the workflow you're trying to implement? Also note that a `Set` is very different from a `Queue`.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. If the queue is full, you always throw away the request that you're about to put in and not something that's already in the queue. Otherwise it wouldn't be a queue.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for [EvictingQueue](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/EvictingQueue.html).  From the documentation:

> A non-blocking queue which automatically evicts elements from the head of the queue when attempting to add new elements onto the queue and it is full.
>
> An evicting queue must be configured with a maximum size. Each time an element is added to a full queue, the queue automatically removes its head element. This is different from conventional bounded queues, which either block or reject new elements when full.